# Unable to archive git repository

Tags: git, gitosis

I'm able to clone a repository with this command:

```
$ git clone ssh://gitosis@myhost.com:22222/MyRepo.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/andrew/MyRepo/.git/
...
```

However, I'm unable to archive it:

```
$ git archive --remote ssh://gitosis@myhost.com:22222/MyRepo.git master
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Unknown command denied
```

Why would `clone` behave differently from `archive`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git archive --remote` requests that the remote performs the archiving for you, something Gitosis doesn't support. There's a [commit on Github](https://github.com/mhaylock/gitosis/commit/a77369f2692f436faf4b88cfa22d0ef5cdce656f) that appears to add this feature.